# Add multiple of a matrix without build a new one

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

Say I have two matrices `B` and `M` and I want to execute the following statement:

```
B += 3*M
```

I execute this instruction repeatedly so I don't want to build each time the matrix `3*M` (`3` may change, it is just to make cleat that I only do a scalar-matrix product). Is it a numpy-function which makes this computation "in place"?

More precisely, I have a list of scalars `as` and a list of matrices `Ms`, I would like to perform the "dot product" (which is not really one since the two operands are of different type) of the two, that is to say:

```
sum(a*M for a, M in zip(as, Ms))
```

The `np.dot` function does not do what I except...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`np.tensordot`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.tensordot.html) -

```
np.tensordot(As,Ms,axes=(0,0))
```

Or [`np.einsum`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) -

```
np.einsum('i,ijk->jk',As,Ms)
```

Sample run -

```
In [41]: As = [2,5,6]

In [42]: Ms = [np.random.rand(2,3),np.random.rand(2,3),np.random.rand(2,3)]

In [43]: sum(a*M for a, M in zip(As, Ms))
Out[43]: 
array([[  6.79630284,   5.04212877,  10.76217631],
       [  4.91927651,   1.98115548,   6.13705742]])

In [44]: np.tensordot(As,Ms,axes=(0,0))
Out[44]: 
array([[  6.79630284,   5.04212877,  10.76217631],
       [  4.91927651,   1.98115548,   6.13705742]])

In [45]: np.einsum('i,ijk->jk',As,Ms)
Out[45]: 
array([[  6.79630284,   5.04212877,  10.76217631],
       [  4.91927651,   1.98115548,   6.13705742]])
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way you could do this, particularly if you favour readability, is to make use of [broadcasting](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html).

So you could make a 3D array from the 1D and 2D arrays and then sum over the appropriate axis:

```
>>> Ms = np.random.randn(4, 2, 3)   # 4 arrays of size 2x3
>>> As = np.random.randn(4)
>>> np.sum(As[:, np.newaxis, np.newaxis] * Ms)
array([[-1.40199248, -0.40337845, -0.69986566],
       [ 3.52724279,  0.19547118,  2.1485559 ]])
>>> sum(a*M for a, M in zip(As, Ms))
array([[-1.40199248, -0.40337845, -0.69986566],
       [ 3.52724279,  0.19547118,  2.1485559 ]])
```

However, it's worth noting that `np.einsum` and `np.tensordot` are usually much more efficient:

```
>>> %timeit np.sum(As[:, np.newaxis, np.newaxis] * Ms, axis=0)
The slowest run took 7.38 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
100000 loops, best of 3: 8.58 µs per loop
>>> %timeit np.einsum('i,ijk->jk', As, Ms)
The slowest run took 19.16 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.44 µs per loop
```

And this is also true for larger numbers:

```
>>> Ms = np.random.randn(100, 200, 300)
>>> As = np.random.randn(100)
>>> %timeit np.einsum('i,ijk->jk', As, Ms)
100 loops, best of 3: 5.03 ms per loop
>>> %timeit np.sum(As[:, np.newaxis, np.newaxis] * Ms, axis=0)
100 loops, best of 3: 14.8 ms per loop
>>> %timeit np.tensordot(As,Ms,axes=(0,0))
100 loops, best of 3: 2.79 ms per loop
```

So `np.tensordot` works best in this case.

The only good reason to use `np.sum` and broadcasting is to make the code a *little* more readable (helps when you have small matrices).