# Matrices addition in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I need to calculate the sum of a list of matrices, however, I can't use `np.sum`, even with `axis=0`, I don't know why. The current solution is a loop, but is there a better way for that?

```
import numpy as np
SAMPLE_SIZES = [10, 100, 1000, 10000]
ITERATIONS = 1
MEAN = np.array([1, 1])
COVARIANCE = np.array([[1, 0.5], [0.5, 1]])
for sample_size in SAMPLE_SIZES:
    max = -1
    for i in range(ITERATIONS):
        xs = np.random.multivariate_normal(MEAN, COVARIANCE, size=sample_size)
        sigma = [[0, 0], [0, 0]]
        for x in xs:
            sigma += np.outer((x-MEAN), (x-MEAN)) / (sample_size-1)
```

In the code above, can I replace the last loop using some `numpy` function? I guess using a loop would be not efficient if the data is very large.

Comment: `SAMPLE_SIZES` is a Python list, not a Numpy array.

Comment: Tell us about `xs`.  Array? List? Shape ,dtype?.  Is `MEAN` a scalar?

Comment: Please show us your erroneous implementation with `np.sum`, and the error message.

Comment: @ÉbeIsaac no, it doesn't, list(range(1)) is [0]

Comment: @ewcz: Sorry, clear now

Comment: MEAN is a numpy array, you can use MEAN=np.array([1, 1]) and COVARIANCE=np.array([[1,1], [1,1]]), then you should be able to run the code. @Praveen

Comment: xs is generated in 6th line @hpaulj

Comment: Generated by `multivariate_normal`?  What's that?  I get parameter error if I  try to use `scipy.stats.multivariate_normal`.  Either fully describe the variables at the problem point, or make it easy to cut-n-paste your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read up about numpy [broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html).

```
xs = np.random.multivariate_normal(MEAN, COVARIANCE, size=sample_size)
```

`xs` now has shape `(sample_size, 2)`, which means you can just subtract `MEAN` directly. You now need to take the outer product between `xs - MEAN` and `xs - MEAN` while adding over the `sample_size` axis. This is best done using [`np.einsum`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html):

```
>>> sigma = np.einsum('ij,ik->jk', xs - MEAN, xs - MEAN) / sample_size
>>> sigma    
array([[ 1.00216043,  0.49549231],
       [ 0.49549231,  1.00004423]])
```

An alternative is to use broadcasting:

```
>>> sigma = np.sum((xs - MEAN)[:, :, np.newaxis]
                   * (xs - MEAN)[:, np.newaxis, :], axis=0) / sample_size
```

Though the broadcasting solution seems easier to understand, `np.einsum` will usually be [more efficient](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39482794/525169) than broadcasting.

**Additional note:** Note that I've divided by `sample_size`, and not by `sample_size - 1`. This is because for estimating the covariance matrix of a random variable with known mean, you need to divide by `sample_size`. Use `sample_size - 1` when you are estimating the mean from the same dataset as well, and using it in your covariance estimate. Otherwise your covariance estimate will be biased.

Comment: Thank you for your help, could you explain a little bit more the additional note? Actually this is part of my homework assignment, I just followed the equation given by professor. But I would like to hear it if this is an error

Comment: @1a1a11a I'd have to give you a whole course on estimation to explain why... Read about unbiased estimators, and then try to derive the unbiased estimator of variance for a gaussian random variable with known mean, and for one with unknown mean.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to compute the empirical covariance then I would suggest using `numpy.cov(xs.T)`.

Otherwise, the last 3 lines can be replaced by:

```
xm = xs - np.mean(xs, axis=0)
sigma = np.inner(xm.T. xm.T) / (sample_size-1)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, but the answer above is more relevant.